# Sed: Ignoring period characters

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I know I can match periods with `\.` but through trial and error I can still not seem to have my pattern ignore the period character.

I have tried variations such as:

`\[^.]`
`\[^.]+`

I want to have code such as

`foo("some text").arg("more text");`

be untouched while code such as

`foo("some text");`

match a pattern and be replaced with something else

### Also, I Have run into another issue

A case such as:

`tr("I am some text")
.arg(i do stuff)
.arg(I also do stuff)`
where it needs to be handled from 2 up to n lines of this.

I want this sort of text to be left alone because as of now, the tr would be deleted and would cause a syntax error.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore" ?  Updating the question and providing some examples of what you want to match why why you want to "ignore" the period character might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be a "non-period" then the sequence `[^.]` is what you want.  In your examples you have a `\` in front of the `[`, which is wrong.

So, for example:

```
foo("some text").arg("more text");
foo("some text");

% sed 's/foo("some text")[^.]/replaced text/' tstfile
foo("some text").arg("more text");
replaced text
```

Note that this also replaced the character following the `foo(..)`.  If you want to keep that then we can remember it:

```
% sed 's/foo("some text")\([^.]\)/replaced text\1/' tstfile
foo("some text").arg("more text");
replaced text;
```

Comment: so for a code `sed -i  '/\btr(/{ :a; s/\btr(\([^)]*\))[^.]/\1/I; t; N; ba}' $file`

how would I keep that non-period character after the text inside the parentheses (\1)

Comment: I'd try replacing `[^.]` with `\([^.]\)` and then have `\1\2` as your replacement

Comment: okay, I was trying that without the two slashes with `\1\2` and that just doesn't make sense. Thanks for opening my eyes